# Gatling 2 how to instrument the DSL

Tags: scala, gatling

Gatling is a great tool to do load testing, but the DSL somehow baffles me.  The problem is that I already have custom request and model classes, and I want to create some kind of "bridge" class to port the existing classes into the DSL.

Here's an example:

```
exec {
  val request = new GetIdRequest()
  request.setCountry("US")
  request // There is an implicit conversion
    .check(status.is(200), bodyString.saveAs("ids"))
}.exec {
  session => 
    val ids = new ObjectMapper().readValue(session("ids").as[String], classOf[IdList])
    val request = new GetObjectRequest()
    val request.setId(id(0))
    request // There is an implicit conversion
      .check(status.is(200), bodyString.saveAs("object"))
    session
}
```

where the implicit conversion just converts the `request` to an `http(...).get(url)...`

This obviously doesn't work,

1. session is immutable, so the "object" value isn't saved to session
2. `request` in the second `exec` is not executed, because it's not passed into `exec` directly

So how can I achieve the desired effect?  Is there an example I can adopt, or do I have to implement my own `ActionBuilder` (I don't want to do this, as this will be like writing another protocol)?  Thanks

**Update 1**

This is the solution I came up with.

I created this translator method

```
def createHttp(name: String, req: Session => HttpRequest): HttpRequestBuilder = {
  http(name)
    .get {
    session => req(session).getUri
  }
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Authorization", {
    session =>
      val r = req(session)
      Authorization.create("GET", r.getUri, appId, appKey)
  })
}
```

Then I just need to pass in a function that creates the `HttpRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you didn't understand is that Gatling DSL components are immutable builders that are resolved and chained once and only once when the Simulation is loaded.

As such, you can:

- neither build requests inside session functions
- nor manually pass some data that has been resolved from the Session

All those happen at runtime, i.e. later.

Your first exec works (even though I would advise against a mutable design) because the block content is static the request is indeed built once.

Your second exec actually create a new request builder every time it's executed, but it's just discarded.

If you really want to write your own DSL, you have to embrace how Gatling works. You can't have it only takes resolved values, like your `setId`, you have to be able to take [Expression](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/expression_el.html)s too.

Also note that your way of saving the whole response body and creating a new ObjectMapper for every execution is both cumbersome and inefficient.

You could simply use a [JsonPath](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/http/http_check.html#http-response-body) check to grab the single id you're interested in, and then use [Gatling EL](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/expression_el.html) to inject the saved value into the next request.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have found a way to bridge the gap, by passing in parameters of type `Session => MyRequest` to a translator method, which translates that into `Expression`.  This works pretty well.